# Is there a way to cache map locally

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

Am using Google Maps Android V2 in my application. It take too much time to load.  do make use of markers to point some particular location. So I was wondering is there a way to cache map or to store a particular area.Is it possible in my app..??

*EDIT*

In default Maps app we can cache the on screen map. How do they do that..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise against such actions(caching the map somehow and displaying it) since it is forbidden by Google terms of use.

There isnt an offline version of Google maps for android(or i am not aware of it, since i couldnt find it when needed a year ago)...the solution is to go with different map api if you really require this.

Are you doing some extensive calculations for your map marker or database work, etc..?

For example i didnt experience slow loading times with google maps when using regular data service internet and loading around 350 map markers on predefined positions...

Comment: if by data service you mean using NETWORK_PROVIDER then yes it takes only few seconds to get current location. But am forced to use GPS_PROVIDER sine the precision of locations matter.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847353/use-google-maps-offline-in-an-app#5896100), how to use google map in offline app. This is based on [osmdroid](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) and also be aware of [Google terms of use](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html) googleMap.